# How do you use a two dimensional array to plot a graph in VBA Excel?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, graph

I am currently trying to create a dynamic graphing code that reads in 5 arrays and plots them on a scatter line graph. I have made the code and read in the 5 arrays.

I do not know how to apply the data that I have to plot in Excel. I am accomplishing this task in a function. Here is what I have currently:

```
Function Graph(ByRef int1 As Variant, ByRef int2 As Variant, ByRef int3 As Variant, _
               ByRef int4 As Variant, ByRef int5 As Variant)

Dim c As Chart
Dim srs As Series
Dim xValues As Variant
Dim yValues As Variant

Set c = ActiveChart
'Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

xValues = Application.Index(int1, 0, 1)
yValues = Application.Index(int1, 0, 2)

With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
    .xValues = xValues
    .Values = yValues
End With

End Function
```

I am trying to use a previously existing graph. The code needs to be able to use the currently selected graph and plot the data as indicated.

Let me know if you need any additional information.

Additional information: I am starting with a blank graph which will accept the arrays as series information (which will in turn populate the graph). If it is easier, I could use VBA to create a chart. I am trying to avoid having to edit the series ranges by hand. I am trying to avoid this because Excel graphs "blank cells" controlled by an equation. I have tried making graphs with large series ranges, but Excel graphs all values.[image: Excel graphing "blank cells"]

This is even considering the check box that says do not graph blank cells.

I have a main function that reads in values and handles the main code. I am going to tie this macro to a button embedded in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Side note: this should probably be a `Sub` instead of a `Function` - you're not returning anything.

Comment: There is a whole list of questions on what exactly you want to do: are you appending the five arrays as series to existing data series, or replacing the existing data series? Are the existing data series already defined as cell ranges on a worksheet? If so, you can just replace the data on the worksheet with the data in your arrays and the chart will update automatically. Even if you're appending additional series to the chart, you can put the array data to some worksheet range and then add those ranges to the chart.

Comment: Are you planning to use this function as a UDF called from a worksheet cell?  That won't work.

Comment: What exactly are you passing in? If you pass in ranges, you can plot them directly as X and Y values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .xValues = xValues
    .Values = yValues
End With
```